# Right Way to Use Module

Tags: ruby, module, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

I wonder what is the right way to use modules. I mean I used them to stock some codes but I have the feeling that modules are intended more to be embed in a class than to be a box that stock code being called directly in a script. So the only right way to stock code is in a class and in modules intended to be extended or included in classes. Am I right ? Little confused..

ps: So rake tasks is not the right way to stock logic codes, rake tasks are only intended to call methods on classes which actually does something. Is it right ?

Comment: IMO they're for both; keeping code in modules makes it cleaner to include in classes, but they're also just for general namespace management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this article series from the [Ruby Best Practices](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/) blog:

- [Issue #8: Uses for Modules (1 of 4)](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/037-issue-8-uses-for-modules.html)
- [Issue #9: Uses for Modules (2 of 4)](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/038-issue-9-uses-for-modules.html)
- [Issue #10: Uses for Modules (3 of 4)](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/040-issue-10-uses-for-modules.html)
- [Issue #11: Uses for Modules (4 of 4)](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/043-issue-11-uses-for-modules.html)