# RIght way of writing module methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what is right way of writing module? is it only used to stock some peace of code to minimize the number of lines, or is it something much more important than that

I have used and seen ways of writing module, I am working on setting up correct way to define and standardised module. this example is kind of controller code that we use in rails

Way 1 :-

```
module B
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def process_items
    # do somthing...
    @items.pluck(:names)
  end
end


Class A
  include B
  
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    @item_names = process_items
  end
end
```

Way 2 :-

```
module B
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def process_items(items)
    # do somthing...
    items.pluck(:names)
  end
end


Class A
  include B
  
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    @item_names = process_items(@items)
  end
end
```

Way 1 :-

1. When I see this independently, its not much readable as I don't know how @items appeared in this method
2. Unit testing would be hard for method as its dependent

Way 2 :-

1. Looking at method I can see input is coming we are processing it and returning it back (readablity is good)
2. Unit testing is easy to this, we wll call method pass what it needs and expect

The way I see modules should be independent, self explanatory, it should be generic so that can be used in any class, kind of helpers. But other way could be dependent on where we use modules

We are using modules like in rails

1. We use conccern in models, when we call module method we can use `self.<field>` we don't need to pass anything because instance variable is supposed to be accesssable in every instance method
2. View helpers are modules I see they put logic into it hard to understand how the variable come from may be instance variable or params, what about making it method which accept somthing and return it back
3. Concerns on controllers, like the example I have given

I would like to have thoughts on this, what is best approach out of it? is it something which can be standarise or it is more situational or I don't know yet :)

Note: -
I was looking at this question but answer given on this question is no more valid as referenced links are not working.
[Right Way to Use Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399413/right-way-to-use-module)

Comment: Re: Way 2. If there's no connection between `Class A` and `module B` then why `include` it? It's a utility method and there's no reason to view it as anything other than that. The point of `include`ing something is when it's coupled to the duck type of `Class A`. Concerns are for *cross-cutting concerns*, which (AFAIK) is why they were named that--something that impacts multiple types.

Answer (score 3):

The difference here is practically academic, as if you have `attr_reader :x` then both `@x` and `x` will have the same meaning.

It's understood that within a mixin module you will be referencing methods and/or variables that are part of the class or module doing the "mixing in". As such, seeing `@x`, or in your case, `@items`, should not come as a real surprise.

If you want to add it as an explicit argument you're sort of missing a lot of the benefits of using a mixin in the first place. You don't need to mix it in at all, you can just use it like `B.process_items(...)`. In other words, your second approach is having an identity crisis. Is it a stand-alone module that includes Concern for no reason, or a weak mixin?

When it comes to testing, you must test the mixin in a module or class which implements the *required* features. In this case you need either an `@items` variable, or an `items` method, and that must have a value of the expected type.

This should be documented somewhere for clarity, but is effectively an implicit [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) with anyone using this module.

Comment: I have some points to make here, when application is complex and big then mixin also managing them becomes headache. May be its more manging and group mixin in right away to make life easier
---
What are your thoughts about view helpers modules? is it right to use instance variables directly over there or we should pass it into methods?

Comment: As they are helpers are so they are supposed to be written in same flow

Comment: View helper modules are, by design, supposed to slot right in to the view as if they lived there. As such it's not uncommon to see them using instance variables directly. They're intended to be simple, not necessarily "clean" from an object-oriented design patterns perspective. It's a pattern specific to Rails, but also one tempered by how Ruby approaches this sort of thing. Pragmatic, easy to use.